# Integrating an image into my executable file

Tags: c++, image, winapi, exe, executable

I have an application that relies on many images.  I have no problem loading the images on to the window.  I would like to make my application have the images integrated into it where there are no actual image files in the folder.  Also, I would like to know how to do this, because if I sell the application I don't want the user to be able to go to the directory my .exe is located in an get the image file (I am aware that they can print screen it).  So, how can I integrate the image into my application.  I am using the WinAPI with C++.

I have searched this multiple times and have not found anything on this.  I have found one question on another forum, but it was asked a long time ago and was not answered.  I did find one other place that had this, but It did not specifically work with my question.

Comment: What is wrong with my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind images (as well as pretty much any pieces of data) as [resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381042.aspx) to your binary.

Comment: Do you mean using a resource (.rc) file?

Comment: That's what I'd do, yes.